# how to set the price for configurable product programmatically

Tags: php, magento-1.7, configurable-product

when i am setting the price 100 or anything, it stored automatically as 0.

$magentoProductModel=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$magentoProductModel->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE);
$magentoProductModel->setPrice(100);
$magentoProductModel->save();